# Silverlight datagrid row edit mode

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a silverlight datagrid with a single editable column. This column has a combo box. To open the combo i have to click on the cell *three* times. Once to select the row, once to enter edit mode, and once to open the combo.

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw6YursbUmI/AAAAAAAAGlg/QJCLu0K7o_8/image_thumb%5B6%5D.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_L9TmtwXFtew/Sw6YursbUmI/AAAAAAAAGlg/QJCLu0K7o_8/image_thumb%5B6%5D.png)

IMHO this is really bad UX so I would like the row to enter edit mode when the user does a row click or mouse over and allow the combo to be opened when with a single click.

The row would then drop out of edit mode if the user does a mouse off the row.

Is this possible? 
What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting datagrid.selectedIndex will fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

Simple way: handle DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp and make your desired behavior.

```
void  MyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender , e)
{         
     if (MyDataGrid.SelectedItem != null)   //ensure we have current item
     {

         //set current column
         MyDataGrid.CurrentColumn = MyDataGrid.Columns[4];

        //call begin edit
        MyDataGrid.BeginEdit();

       //now open combobox 
       MyComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;   // a.) 
   }
}
```

I hope you catch the ideea.

a) * here I'm not sure if 100% working.
(and, of course,  you need a reference to MyComboBox (ComboBox control defined in column template)*

Good luck
rlodina

Comment: Just out of dumb curiosity, has this been tested as of yet?  I ask because I need somewhat similar functionality, but need to be able to navigate the grid using the arrow keys, and then allow the user to, with the start of a keystroke, begin editing without the click, and click that you typically have to do.  Thx.

Comment: New to this so, how do you get reference to MyComboBox?